# Lync Powershell script to enable a user but use their secondary SMTP address for the SIP

Tags: powershell, sip, lync

I have a Script that enabled Lync users from a CSV and puts the SIP address and users name into a text. Now i am using their Exchange email address as the SIP, problem is some users have a primary address from outside the company that Lync cant use, but they do have a company email as their secondary, what i am trying to do is set a command that checks the email addresses for a user and can select the appropriate company email address if there is a different primary. Maybe what i am trying to do is than what Lync can do or maybe i am going about this wrong. Any insight would be awesome.

Comment: sounds like you would need to get all email addresses of users and set a $primaryemail variable to the company one before assigning it. Do you have some code to show where you need to insert the logic

Comment: This is the code i am using for provisioning at this moment

$csv = Import-CSV D:\lync_creation\userlog.csv
# Account Provisioning
foreach($c in $csv){ 
    "Enabling $($c.Identity) for Lync 2010" 
    Enable-csuser -identity $c.Identity -registrarpool pool01.west.com –sipaddresstype EmailAddress
}   
# On Screen output and wait for processing to complete 
 Write-host "Waiting for 5 seconds"
Sleep -m 5000;
# SIP Retrieval and out to TXT File